# Break an array into different arrays containing x elements each

Tags: php

If I have a single array that has around 5000 elements.

I want 50 arrays out it having 100 elements each. And of course if there are 4923 elements, out of the 50 arrays, there will be 23 in the last one.

I know there must be some built-in function for this. But can't get around one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is https://www.php.net/array_chunk

```
$splitted = array_chunk($my_array, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks! Just couldn't recall the function name.